# A person or large groupe of people who came in my city from another city and stayed to find work or just to live but they are not really welcome

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, expressions, phrase-requests, american-english

Almost like immigrants but they are not from other countries. In my language, we have a single word to describe such phenomenon, wanted to know if there is one in English. 
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U. What is the word you use in your language?

Comment: Hi, "понаехали" - is a verb and "понаехвшие" - is a participle. It's Russian language.

Comment: Ok, good so far. Now if you could write a sentence demonstrating _how_ the target language is to be used, and we could get started...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One word is **interlopers**. The [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/interloper) gives this definition for **interloper**

> A person who becomes involved in a place or situation where they are
>   not wanted or are considered not to belong.

One example usage is

> But when Independence came, some Africans looked on the Asians as
>   interlopers, foreigners depriving the locals of jobs and economic
>   opportunity.

Comment: The [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interloper) has this example: *summer residents were regarded as interlopers who had no deep commitment to the town's welfare*. So **interlopers** are not necessarily from another country.

Comment: Thanks one more time. That's exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: Yeah, sure. Did it all.

Answer (score 0):

In the Southern US, there is a common term for this kind of person.  It is a carpetbagger.  It was used after the Civil War to describe people who came from out-of-town, generally the North to describe how they carried their possessions - in a [bag made of carpet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carpet_bag).